# How to output the value returned by a function that is a float in C

Tags: c, function

The question is that I have to prompt the user to enter the base and height of a triangle as a float, pass it too a function where the function will get the area of the triangle, return it to main. the problem is that the output of the area is 0.000000.

its also giving me a warning

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Warning C4477   'printf' : format string '%f' requires an argument of type 'double', but variadic argument 1 has type 'float (__cdecl *)(float,float)'  line 38.
```

What am I doing wrong?

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>


float area(float base,float height);


int main()
{   

float height;
printf("Enter an height: ");
scanf_s("%f", &height);
printf("Number = %f", height);

float base;
printf("Enter an base: ");
scanf_s("%f", &base);
printf("Number = %f", base);

area(height, base);

printf("area of triangle : %f\n", area);

return 0;

}

float area(float base, float height)
{

float half = .5;
float area = half * base * height;

return area;

}
```

Comment: `area(height, base);

printf("area of triangle : %f\n", area);` --> `printf("area of triangle : %f\n", area(base, height));`

Comment: `area` is a function. You call it once with `area(height, base)`, but you never assigned the result to a variable. Then, when you try to pass `area` to `printf`, you're passing a function, not the result of that function.

Comment: Also: There's absolutely no reason to have the `half` and `area` temporary variables. Yes, magic numbers like `.5` are bad, but extract it to a variable named `half` adds no additional information.

Comment: I just have to go on record as saying:  "Anyone who can get **both** `printf()` and `scanf()` right before knowing how to invoke a function is probably hiding some brilliance somewhere...

Answer (score 2):

Your primary issue is that you're passing a function (`area`), instead of the result of function invocation (`area(height, base)`). You need to store the result to a variable, then print that variable.

```
float computedArea = area(height, base);
printf("area of triangle : %f\n", computedArea);
```

Or you can just call the function, in-place, which work in this case, because it doesn't make the line too long:

```
printf("area of triangle : %f\n", area(height, base));
```

Here's how I would write this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

double area(double base,double height);

int main() {  
    printf("Enter the height: ");
    double height;
    scanf("%lf", &height);
    printf("Height: %f\n", height);

    printf("Enter the base: ");
    double base;
    scanf("%lf", &base);
    printf("Base: %f\n", base);

    double computedArea = area(height, base);

    printf("Triangle Area: %f\n", computedArea);
    return 0;
}

double area(double base, double height) {
    return (base * height) / 2.0;
}
```

Comment: @ebyrob `printf` and `scanf` have different format string specs. `%f` is `double` for `printf`, but `float` for `scanf`. To get `scanf` to read in a `double`, you need the "long float" `%lf` token

Comment: My bad.  I knew there was a reason I don't use `scanf()` in production code.  I think it's probably heavy handed to recommend changing already correct code, but it's definitely worth pointing out the rocky waters here.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142993/discussion-between-alexander-and-ebyrob).

Comment: "You need to store the result to a variable, then print that variable." misleads about its necessity  as [printing directly the function result](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43702340/2410359) is OK.  Savings it first though does improve clarity.

Comment: Just for the record, `%lf` is allowed in printf since C99, but the `l` is ignored and adds nothing except a bit of consistency with scanf.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
area(height, base); // invoking a function without capturing its output

printf("area of triangle : %f\n", area); // area refers to the memory location where the function resides.
```

to

```
printf("area of triangle : %.2f\n", area(height, base));
 // Directly passing the area output to printf. The '.2' specifies the precision you want
```

Comment: I'm not sure how this adds anything new.